# Interior of connected subset of $\mathbb R$ is connected?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

How would you show the interior of a connected sets of $\mathbb{R}$ is connected? In general is any open subsets of connected subsets $\mathbb{R}$ connected?

Comment: What is your definition of connectedness?

Comment: False, consider two circles joined at a point, the interior will not be connected, even though they are.

Comment: @AlecTeal he is asking for connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ !

Answer (score 3):

A connected subset $E$ of $\mathbb R$ has the property that if $x < y$ are points in $E$ and $x < z < y$, then $z \in E$. Thus $E$ is an interval (possibly unbounded) and so is its interior.